# Pycharm: Exceptions settings behaving differently between tests and normal program execution

Tags: debugging, pycharm

How do I setup Pycharm so that it stops only on uncaught exceptions both while debugging normal programs as well as tests?

I currently have

- On termination checked
- On raise unchecked
- Ignore library files unchecked

This is my code:

```
try:
    raise Exception('caught')
except:
    print('caught exception')

raise Exception('uncaught')
```

When I name the file so that it gets treated as a normal script, my program suspends when the uncaught Exception is raised. However, when I rename the script so that it has the 'test' prefix, it won't stop there, unless I enable 'On raise' but then, it stops on every exception, even the caught ones which I don't need. What do I need to change in my settings to get consistent debug behavior?

[image: I want it to break]